# Upgrade apache storm (1.0.0 to 1.2.3)

Tags: java, apache-storm

I needed update apache storm 1.0.0 to latest version 1.x.x (1.2.3). What is the steps need? What is the changes in storm configuration file? Is there any guide that help (migration)?
 thank you so much

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? Normally there are release notes or upgrade information.

Comment: It's complicated... There are many versions among these.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe (but could be wrong) that there are any breaking changes in the configuration file between 1.0.0 and 1.2.3. Migration should follow the usual steps for Storm upgrades:

- Upgrade your Storm hosts one at a time by

  - Downloading the 1.2.3 binary release
  - Shutting down the Storm services running on the host (e.g. workers, supervisor, Nimbus)
  - Extracting the 1.2.3 release, and making any adjustments to the configuration files you had in the old install
  - Restarting your Storm services on that host, using the new install instead of the old install

You may also want to

- Upgrade your topologies to build against the version of Storm you're upgrading to (optional, but can help catch any compile-time errors in non-core modules that may have changed within the major version, such as `storm-kafka-client`)

This way you can upgrade with no downtime. Of course if you don't care about downtime you can just shut down the whole cluster, do the steps outlined above, then restart the cluster using the new installs.

Edit: You're asking about the full diff of configuration options between 1.2.3 and 2.0.0. You can find every configuration option for 1.2.3 [here](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.3/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/Config.java), and the full list of configuration options for 2.0.0 [here](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v2.0.0/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/Config.java) and [here](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v2.0.0/storm-server/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/DaemonConfig.java).

Comment: Thank you for your information, but I need the all changes in storm configuration file.